# PHP RFI : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a challenge on a famous security website !

The challenge is to exploit a Remote file Inclusion breach !

I've located the exploit and i can make the server run php function !

But not all !!! I don't know why !

So by example I can run the `phpinfo();` function by encoding :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

In base64 - Ascii, this works perfectly but my goal is to get the php source code !

But when i'm encoding :

```
<?php file('index.php'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php $page = file_get_contents('index.php'); echo $page; ?>
```

I use to get an Error !Like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'`

Thanks for your help ! I think that the problem come from the output (when i do the "echo")

Comment: `<?php $page = file_get_contents('index.php'); echo $page; ?>` should load the file and output as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try base64 encoding `$page` before sending it back.

```
<?php $page = file_get_contents('index.php'); echo base64_encode($page); ?>
```

and then decoding later on your machine.